# need to my server's ip changes when it needs to connect port 'x' on ip 'y'

Tags: iptables, ip, proxy

simple question: "need a way to proxify a port"

I have a linux server and have a proxy server on another machine.

My linux server needs connect to port 'x' on ip 'y'

Is it possible to create iptables rule or another way to: when my linux server tries to connect to port 'x' on ip 'y' uses my proxy server on another machine?

In other words, I need to my server's ip changes when it needs to connect port 'x' on ip 'y' by using another proxy server machine.

Comment: [**Don't cross-post**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting). You've already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266676/need-to-my-servers-ip-changes-when-it-needs-to-connect-port-x-on-ip-y and http://serverfault.com/questions/381935/need-to-my-servers-ip-changes-when-it-needs-to-connect-port-x-on-ip-y

Comment: What kind of proxy (SOCKS, HTTP, FTP, …)? Or do you simply want to redirect TCP traffic?

Comment: @Gilles it is socks. no i need proxify a specific port.

Comment: I'm still unclear on what you're asking. "need to my server's ip changes" seems like it's missing a verb. Need to log? Need to redirect? Need to block? Is the idea that the proxy is *not* used by linux box *unless* it is specifically attempting to connect to y:x ?

Comment: @ckhan need a way to proxify a port

Comment: Sorry, proxify is not a word or a term I've ever heard in common usage. Do you mean the service Proxify.com ?

Comment: @ckhan no, use a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done at the TCP layer because the application won't be using the SOCKS protocol and so the SOCKS server can't understand the request. You can look into using [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/) to transparently send traffic from certain application(s) via the SOCKS server. You can configure tsocks to select the proxy based on the destination and port number, using the [`reaches`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/tsocks.conf.5.html#contenttoc2) configuration directive.